# error:- service class has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android, service

I am new to android. I want to use service inside my activity for fetching the JSON data after interval of time. My service class is a inner class of my record class. I made an empty constructor of my service class and tried different approaches but every time I get into an error. Can anyone please guide me on this problem?

record.class

```
public class record extends Activity{
.....
private static String url ="https://podgier-woman.000webhostapp.com/table.php";
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
......
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record);
    ......

    Intent intent = new Intent(record.this,
            BackgroundService.class);

    startService(intent);

}


    class gro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      ............
        }
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        java.util.List<NameValuePair> pr = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", pr);

        try {
            JSONArray code = json.getJSONArray("code");
            Log.d("list :",code.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = code.getJSONObject(i);

                asd.add(c.getString("name"));

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                // adding contact to contact list
                JSONArray p = null;
            }
            }catch(JSONException e){

            }
            return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        ..........

        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(info));
        customList = new CustomList(record.this,info);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(customList);


    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class BackgroundService extends Service
{
    public BackgroundService(){
        super();
    }

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
    private ThreadGroup myThreads = new ThreadGroup("ServiceWorker");



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(TAG, "in onCreate()");

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        int counter = intent.getExtras().getInt("counter");



        Log.v(TAG, "in onStartCommand(), counter = " + counter +
                ", startId = " + startId);

        new Thread(myThreads, new ServiceWorker(counter), "BackgroundService")
                .start();


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    class ServiceWorker implements Runnable
    {
        private int counter = -1;

        public ServiceWorker(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        public void run() {

            final String TAG2 = "ServiceWorker:" + Thread.currentThread().getId();
            // do background processing here...
            try {
                Log.e(TAG2, "sleeping for 5 seconds. counter = " + counter);

                while(true)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    Log.e("agdghdgdgdrgrdgrdg","dgdgd");
                    new gro().execute();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG2, "... sleep interrupted");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "in onBind()");
        return null;
    }


}



}
```

manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.grover.jsonp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".record"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".record$BackgroundService"/>
</application>
```

logcat

```
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.grover.jsonp, PID: 13046
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.grover.jsonp.record$BackgroundService: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.grover.jsonp.record$BackgroundService has no zero argument constructor
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2721)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
               Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.grover.jsonp.record$BackgroundService has no zero argument constructor
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2718)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2718) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Comment: Should have performed some R & D before asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to launch a `Bounded Service` using an `Intent`. Which is wrong. In order to do that you need to create an `Intent Service`

You are getting a zero argument constructor exception because of you didn't bind your service to your MainActivity" is incorrect, as the problem with the constructor has nothing to with whether startService() or bindService() is used. ([Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438539/error-service-class-has-no-zero-argument-constructor/45438687?noredirect=1#comment77839379_45438687))

To create a BoundService, you need an `iBinder` object to bind your service.  I know it's quite weird but this is how Android get's to know it. As you would have read, there are two kinds of services

```
 1. Intent Service
 2. Bound Service
```

The `Bound Service` needs to be instantiated like this.

edit your code with this, make sure you update your `onBind()` with mine.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service
{
    public BackgroundService(){
        super();
    }
    private BackgroundService mBS;

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
    // RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

     /**
     * Class for clients to access.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with
     * IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BackgroundService getService() {
            return BackgroundService.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "in onBind()");
        return mBinder;
    }

}
```

in your MainActivity you need an **interface** --> `ServiceConnection`

Add the following in your `MainActivity.java`

```
BackgroundService mBackgroundService;
boolean mServiceBound = false;

private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    mServiceBound = false;
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    LocalBinder  myBinder = (LocalBinder ) service;
    mBackgroundService = myBinder.getService();
    mServiceBound = true;
}
};
     //Start the service when the activity starts
     @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mServiceBound) {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mServiceBound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain **in detail** how this clears up the exception stated in the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare kindly have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Well explained, You didn't have to down vote it @CommonsWare.

Comment: This still does not explain how this clears up the exception stated in the question. It is also riddled with mistakes. For example, "You are getting a zero argument constructor exception because you didn't bind your service to your MainActivity" is incorrect, as the problem with the constructor has nothing to with whether `startService()` or `bindService()` is used.

Comment: Are your sure?  Kindly tell us what is the problem then :/ @CommonsWare

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, I am quite certain. It is impossible for the framework to create an instance of the service in the question, because the service in the question is a nested class. The error message is somewhat misleading in this case -- it's not that the zero-argument constructor does not exist, but that it is unusable by anything other than an instance of the outer class.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Yea makes sense, It's because the service has been registered in the Manifest file but won't be instantiated because it's a `bounded` service not `intent` service. Thus leads to this error. Right?

Comment: @Dennis: No, as [I mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438539/error-service-class-has-no-zero-argument-constructor/45438687?noredirect=1#comment77839379_45438687).

Comment: Then why is it happening? Do you know the answer?

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, as [I explained previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438539/error-service-class-has-no-zero-argument-constructor/45438687?noredirect=1#comment77839517_45438687).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150729/discussion-between-dennis-and-commonsware).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, can you please reply to my question in the chat? Thanks!